# Node, best way to check users in db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'd like to ask what is the best way to check if an user already exist and throw an error in Mongo DB. I was trying with express-validator but I don't think that it's a correct practice.

I've been trying with this code and everything is fine except the custom username part. I'm not able to make this code working so maybe there is a better way to do it, not necessarily easier.

```
router.post('/register', function(req,res) {
        const name = req.body.name;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const username = req.body.username;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const password2 = req.body.password2;

        //Looking for errors
        req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Wrong email format').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(password);
        req.check('username').custom(value => {
            return User.findOne({username: username}, function(err,result) {
                if(err) throw err;
                if(result) {
                    console.log(result.username);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: So once I submit it, should I create a function in the res that will be looking for the second user with the same name and delete it?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot you were using mongoDB, so my advice was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could make a query to check if the username is unique in the database.

```
User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (result) throw('User already exists!');
});
```

But *mongoose* schema gives you the possibility to make a field unique, so you do not have to worry about it any more.

```
const User = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  password: String
})
```

No needs to make a custom validation on that field, just throw the error on insert if it already exists.
Note that it's usually the email field that is defined as unique in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that's I've been looking for, I should put this in a function immediatly.